# Shorthand for groovy String

Tags: groovy

If I am using Groovy String Template:
http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/template-engines.html#markuptemplate-gotchas

I have a variable $name1,name2 and I want to says something like:

```
${name1? name1:''} ${name2? 'name2 was here, too': ''}
```

Is there a cleaner way to write expression like this. 
Given I don't know if $name1, $name2 is null or not. If they are, printing empty   or not printing anything is fine. I just don't want 'null' as the text.

Answer (score 1):

There is such thing as an Elvis operator:

```
def foo = bar?:baz
```

Which is equal to calling:

```
def foo = bar ? bar : baz
```

In your case, you can use it like this:

```
${name1?:''}
```

Comment: nitpicking: the equivalent code is `bar ? bar : baz`; groovy thruth instead of a null check.

Comment: @cfrick thanks for pointing that out, I've edited that into the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
${name1 ?: ''} ${name2 ? 'name2 was here, too' : ''}
```